# Array inside ArrayList Loop to fake DB

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am learning Java so I am trying to create a very basic program that can create, contain, show and erase accounts.

The thing is I thought about creating an ArrayList (because it can grow itself instead of putting a counter, I guess) which contains a normal Array with all the variables with the information of this customers inside.

So, basically the arrayList should contain the columns and grow when needed to register a new customer and the Array (with a fixed lengt) to save all the data of the customer.

I already looked and read a lot but not able to find a solution.

The code below is the customer creation method, I need to understand how can I use a for loop to fill the arrays and then search, erase or edit a customer based in ID.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class CustomersDB {

private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private ArrayList<String[]> custList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] newCustomer = new String[9];

        System.out.println("Name: ");
        newCustomer[0] = scanner.nextLine();
        setCustName(newCustomer[0]);

        System.out.println("Surname: ");
        newCustomer[1] = scanner.nextLine();
        setCustSurname(newCustomer[1]);

        System.out.println("ID: ");
        newCustomer[2] = scanner.nextLine();
        setCustSurname(newCustomer[2]);

        custList.add(newCustomer);
```

Comment: Hi Luis, welcome to StackOverflow. You may consider using a Map - a collection that maps keys to values, with a customer's id as the key. This collection has methods that allow you to search and erase a value with the given key. If the ordering of the rows is important to you, you may consider a TreeMap, that will allow you to iterate the entries by id.

Comment: I should use only what I have been taught on the course :s so: for loops, while, if, array and arraylist, constructors, getters and setters, basic things :s